# If else with list comprehension in haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I was writing a code which has a if else with list comprehension is it allowed and if not how else can i write this code?

```
valid :: [(String, Int)]-> [String]-> [(String, Int)]
vaild dict words = [if checks word dict
                    then (word, scores word)|word <- words ]
```

where check gives a bool value

Comment: I suppose you only wanted a list of words that exist in the dictionary. So you need the condition in the enumeration part: `[(word, scores word)| word <- words, checks word dict]`

Comment: In Haskell the `else` clause is not optional in an `if ... then ... else ...` expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Haskell everything has a type right? So `if checks word dict then ...` has a specific type,
in this case `(String, Int)`. Imagine if `checks word dict` was false, we still need to produce something of type `(String, Int)` so what on earth could we do?

To avoid this obvious quagmire, Haskell **requires** an `else` clause always. Its more accurate to think of `if then else` as something like C's `foo ? bar : baz` (ternary operator).

In a list comprehension however, there's a nice solution. You can put predicates in the body of the comprehension to "guard" what reaches the left side

```
[(word, scores word) | word <- words, checks word dict]
```

This basically words by selecting each word in `words` and then checking `checks word dict`, if this returns false, we "skip" this element.

There's actually a connection to monads and something called `MonadPlus`, but I won't mention this because I think it will only serve to confuse you :) It's alright to treat it as magic for a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you have been downvoted. As the comment to your question states, you probably want something like this:

```
valid :: [(String, Int)]-> [String]-> [(String, Int)]
valid dict words = [(word, scores word) | word <- words, checks word dict]
```

This is pretty similar to how you would achieve it in Python.

Alternatively, you can do this with the "do" notation:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

valid :: [(String, Int)]-> [String]-> [(String, Int)]
valid dict words = do 
    word <- words
    guard (checks word dict)
    return (word, scores word)
```

Or, if you don't want to use list comprehensions at all, something like this would work:

```
import Control.Arrow

valid :: [(String, Int)]-> [String]-> [(String, Int)]
valid dict words = map (id &&& scores) $ filter (\word -> checks word dict) words
```

which can be simplified even further like this:

```
import Control.Arrow

valid :: [(String, Int)]-> [String]-> [(String, Int)]
valid dict = map (id &&& scores) . filter (flip checks dict)
```

Comment: Im also not sure why this is downvoted.. I've upvoted to counteract the rep change. It seems like a perfectly fine beginner question to me